# SwiftUI. How to clear navigation history without popping?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to push a view and clear the navigation history. With UIKit I can just call `setViewControllers([NewController()], animated: true)`. How can I do the same thing using SwiftUI.

Comment: You can use topViewController to get the top controller and then do the same thing.

Comment: How you can do this, depends on how you have "pushed" your views with NavigationLink. Basically, when your NavigationLink is not "activated", then there is no view "pushed". Also, in your case you need to have a condition in the link, which switches to different views. This might be the more tricky part. Show what you have so far, please.